# No module named difflib

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, scriptengine

I want to execute python code from C# with following code.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"F:\Script\extracter.py");
        source.Execute();
    }
```

I have the problem at line source.Execute(), I got error "No module named difflib". 
What is wrong in my code?

This is my python code (extracter.py).

```
import re
import itertools
import difflib
print "Hello"
```

Comment: This is a real shot in the dark, but what Python version are you running?

Comment: I'm using IronPython 2.6 (2.6.10920.0) on .NET 2.0.50727.1433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like your engine does not have access to Python standard library - it does not see `difflib.py`. Either fix the `sys.path` or copy `difflib.py` from Python 2.6 to `f:\script` folder.

`re` and `itertools` modules are written in C# and are part of `IronPython.modules.dll` - that's why importing them work.